# Using Singleton to Share a Variable

Tags: java, blackberry

I have been having a hard time understanding how to use a singleton to share a common variable. I am trying to make a blackberry app which has two entry points which need to share a common variable, iconCount. I have been advised to use a singleton with the RunTimeStore API by someone on a forum. Googling around eventually leads to:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/CS_creating_a_singleton_by_using_rutnime_store_1554335_11.jsp

I have been a few pages deep in Google but I still can`t understand what this does and how to implement it. My current understanding is that a singleton will create a "global variable" somehow through the code:

```
class MySingleton {
   private static MySingleton _instance;
   private static final long GUID = 0xab4dd61c5d004c18L;

   // constructor
   MySingleton() {}

   public static MySingleton getInstance() {
      if (_instance == null) {
         _instance = (MySingleton)RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().get(GUID);
      if (_instance == null) {
         MySingleton singleton = new MySingleton();

         RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().put(GUID, singleton);
         _instance = singleton;
         }
      }
      return _instance;
   }
}
```

And another question would be how would I create a variable from this singleton? I need to declare variable iconCount = 0 at the beginning and then be able to use it. Would declaring it be something like

```
Integer iconCount = (Integer) RuntimeStore.getInstance();
```

? This is very new to me as I have just started Java so if anyone could explain this keeping in mind you're communicating with a novice I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean please make sure that user initializing MySingleton class just onetime so you will not have problem with multiple instances and initialize two count in the same time. I mean from multiple instance something like below:

```
Mysingleton single = new Mysingleton();
Mysingleton single2 = new Mysingleton();
```

Because both initilaization can have diffetent count. You need something like this:

```
public class IconManager {
    private static iconManager _instance;
    private static final long GUID = 0xab4dd61c5d004c18L;
    private static int count = 0;

    // constructor
    IconManager() {
    }

    public static IconManager getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = (IconManager) RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().get(GUID);
            if (_instance == null) {
                IconManager singleton = new IconManager();

                RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().put(GUID, singleton);
                _instance = singleton;
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public static void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
```

}

and after you can create an instance for the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    IconManager iconManager = IconManager.getInstance();
    iconManager.setCount(iconmanager.getCount() + 1);

}
```

So application will do first validation, if there is already an instance it will update existing one, if not than it will create new one.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, the line IconManager.getRuntimeStore().put(GUID, singleton); doesn't seem to work because there is no method from IconManager that has getRuntimeStore(). It only works if I do RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().put(GUID, singleton);I will test the technique right now

Answer (score 1):

You would call

`MySingleton.getInstance()`

to get the instance in your app.  The point is that `getInstance` is controlling access to the underlying object.

Also, you should make your constructor private, so it's only accessible in that file.

To define a property on you singleton class, just declare a non-static property.  Each instance of the class will have its own copy, but you are controlling the creation of the objects, so their should only ever be 1 (per JVM).  So

```
class MySingleton {
   private static MySingleton _instance;
   private static final long GUID = 0xab4dd61c5d004c18L;

   private Integer iconCount; // non-static method, add a public getIconCount below
  ...
}
```

and then you can access it via

`MySingleton.getInstance().getIconCount();`

Comment: Given that both if statements have differing code initializing the instance, it appears that there may be 2 ways to instantiate the instance. One from scratch, a second from a "runtimeStore". It seems like it tries to get the singleton from a cache, and if it's not there it creates it. This seems "semi" valid.

Comment: @rfreak, thanx, it still irks me though, but it's not absolutely broken

Comment: totally agree on that point. It seems wrong. I don't know jack about Blackberry programming though, so figured it might be something specific to the programming environment there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast your MySingleton class to Integer.

And in your example you don't use your singleton but RuntimeStore !

You can use an integer field of your class Singleton, initalized to 0 in the constructor of your singleton (private constructor) and get it by doing :

```
MySingleton.getInstance().getIntegerField()
```

here is a detailled description of the singleton pattern : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

I think you misunderstand the use of the singleton. the singleton is not injected in your RuntimeStore, it is a classic java object. The only subtile think to know about a singleton is that its constructor is private and the class MySingleton can have only one instance which is always returned when your singleton.getInstance() is called